# Assign values to Obj-C struct from C

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, objective-c++

I declare my struct in a header file like so:

```
typedef struct MyStruct{
    int test;
} MyStruct;

@interface StructTestingFile
MyStruct *originalStruct;
@end
```

Then from the .mm file, I call

```
originalStruct = loadTestInt();
```

In the C file, here is what I'm doing:

```
extern "C" MyStruct* loadTestInt()
{
    MyStruct *aStruct;

    aStruct->test = 1;

    return aStruct;
}
```

Every time it crashes on assigning `aStruct->test = 1`.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: I think it's because you're not allocating my struct. That first line in the C file creates which set to null, then you're trying to assign to null so you crash with a NullPointerException or something to that effect. Try calling malloc in that first line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a pointer but not allocating memory for the struct itself;

```
MyStruct *aStruct;

aStruct = (MyStruct*)malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));

aStruct->test = 1;
```

Comment: That makes sense and answers my question.  However, I get an error saying `Cannot initialize a variable of type "MyStruct*" with an rvalue of type "void*"` ?  Any ideas?

Comment: Try casting: `aStruct = (MyStruct *)malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));`

Comment: @karl_ Sorry, updated the answer, you'll need to cast the result of malloc to the correct type.

Comment: Yay Objective-C++.  I'll retag the question to match.

Comment: Awesome, that did the track.  I guess I've got to get better at reading compiler errors.  Now that you pointed out the casting issue it seems glaringly obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer causes undefined behaviour.  `aStruct` doesn't point to anything when you do that assignment.  Allocate some space, and you'll be off to the races:

```
extern "C" MyStruct* loadTestInt()
{
  MyStruct *aStruct = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
  aStruct->test = 1;
  return aStruct;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers so far have pointed to the error of using pointers and not allocating memory.

However do you really want to use a pointer to your struct at all? A struct is a value-type (POD in C-ese), you can just pass them around the same as you would, say, an integer. Unless your structure is large, or *identity* is important (using identity to mean that two pointers refer to the exact same memory), dynamically allocating a struct is probably just work you don't need - especially as you have to free it later.

For comparison here is your code without pointers:

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
   int test;
} MyStruct;

@interface StructTestingFile
{
   MyStruct originalStruct;
}
@end
```

And:

```
extern "C" MyStruct loadTestInt()
{
   MyStruct aStruct;

   aStruct.test = 1;

   return aStruct;
}
```